# Using variable inside of ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have table with many ngFor, how I can do local variable in HTML from item of getList()?

I need user # ?

example:
`<div *ngFor="let #item of getList()"></div>` ? and how I can used local variable in next ngFor HTML ?

Comment: add your `getList()` method here

Comment: Can you please share some more of your code and explain further what you want to achieve? I don't fully understand what you want to do.

Comment: I have ngFor in table thead tr and i need use element of ngFor in table body. example <thead><tr *ngFor="let item of getList()"></tr></thead> and I need used this item in table body tags. How i can get local variable from item of getList() ?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myList" #item></div>
```

- `item` refers to each item in `myList`
- `#item` is the reference to the element in the DOM

**Typescript**

```
export class YourComponent {

    get myList(): any[] {
        return this.mySpecialList;
    }

}
```

You can use the `get` function `myList` to bind a custom array to the `*ngFor` (the array will automatically update if something changes, too)

P.S.: I am not quite sure if I understood your issue correctly. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yes, I know but I dont need bind myList but item, because i need item variable not myList. Have another idea to get variable from item of ngFor ?

Comment: Can't you just use `item.proporty` to get the variables?

Comment: Yes I used item.property to get variables into HTML but I need get all items because I must used *ngIf and compare value.property from table body tag to item.property from table thead tag.

Comment: You might try adding the index to the `*ngFor`: `<div *ngFor="let item of getList(); let i = index"></div>` and then you can compare `item` with `otherList[i]`

Comment: I cant because item list is groupby but otherList[i] not, so cant do this, summarizing I must have more that one ngFor with item.

Comment: I suggest posting your issue in more detail so that we can understand the actual problem better

Answer (score 0):

I have table example:

```
<div class="card mb-4">
  <div class="card-body card-table">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="align-middle">Przydział:</th>
            <th class="align-middle" *ngFor="let distinctStatus of groupByList(list, 'status')">{{distinctStatus.status}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let distinctId of groupByList(list, 'id')">
            <td class="align-middle">{{distinctId.id}}</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-right" *ngFor="let distinctStatus of groupByList(list, 'status')">
              <span *ngFor="let value of groupByList(list, 'id', 'status')">
                <span *ngIf="value.id == distinctId.id && value.status == distinctStatus.status">{{value.number}}</span>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle font-weight-bold">Razem:</td>
            <td class="align-middle text-right font-weight-bold" *ngFor="let distinctStatus of groupByList(list, 'status')">
              <span *ngFor="let value of groupByList(list, 'status')">
                <span *ngIf="value.status == distinctStatus.status">{{value.number}}</span>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I can get distinctStatus variable from thead tr th because I need use this variable with ngIf in body tr td (compare value.property with distinct.property. Now I have many ngFor because I cant get distinctStatus variable after ngFor scope.